# How to scroll to a UIActionSheet cell where title is equal to a certain NSString value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

How to scroll to a `UIActionSheet` cell where title is equal to a certain `NSString` value?
(I'm sure a tableview would be better etc... but this is what I have at the moment and need a solution for my current dilemma).

Could I use something like the following to scroll down to the row based on a certain `NSString` value when the actionsheet comes into view? If so how do I code the `NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row`? I get undeclared identifier row at the moment.

```
[actionSheet scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
```

I'm able to get the title text of the action sheet row with:

```
    actionSheetSelectedCity = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex: buttonIndex]];
```

Comment: `UIActionSheet` is a `UIView`. It does not have a method named `scrollToRowIndexPath:...`. It provides no API for any scrolling. If you need to do something that the API of the standard UI component doesn't provide, then you need to use a different component or create your own.

Comment: I see. I am able to scroll it though when I add more than 8 items. I guess it's not possible to have it load and scroll to a certain row though. thanks